# Publishing HTML private repository using GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to publish an HTML static website from gitlab. Is it possible? Using GitHub, I published some free websites but GitHub isn't free for private repositories.

Comment: You could use bitbucket where you can have private repositories and then use pipelines for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a similar to GitHub Pages [product](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/index.html) from GitLab.

[Here](https://gitlab.com/pages/) you can see the examples of statically generated sites using this feature.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Pages item in the Settings menu on gitlab.com. What else do I need to configure? Do I need to be an owner?